# Is there a way to get an Image from byte array? [WASM]

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

I want to get an image that I have in byte[] but when I want to use System.Drawing.Image.FromStream it says that is not available on UWP and WASM, so I was wondering if there is a way to convert my byte[] to an image in C# (specifically on WASM) or I have to use javascript?

Comment: Do you know the encoded format of the image in the byte array? (JPEG, BMP, raw pixels?).

Comment: Yes, I have all the information about the image I just need a way to convert it.

Comment: Do you just need to display the image on the screen, or you want to create a file from it?

Comment: I want to display it on the screen using XAML and C# if I can.

Comment: @Cajaaa You need to share what kind of image it is, the answer depends on that. So is when you say you have an image as bytes, is it encoded in JPEG, PNG or something, or is it an array of raw pixel values?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the image on screen you'll want to create a [BitmapImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage) which can be done as shown in [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33539437/628821) but passing your byte array into the constructor of the MemoryStream.

The BitmapImage can the be assigned to the Image's Source property.

P.S. Note the further comment in the answer linked to above in case it's of use:

> Besides, BitmapImage has a UriSource property, you can just use this property to get online image.